# Find the domain of $f\circ g$ and $g \circ f$, given $f(x) = \log x$ and $g(x) =\sin x$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, logarithms

> Find the domain of $f\circ g$ and $g \circ f$, given $f(x) = \log x$ and $g(x) =\sin x$

- $f(x)=\log x$ is defined when  $x>0$, therefore $f(\sin(x))= \log (\sin x)$ is defined when $\sin x >0$

It follows  $D_{f\circ g}= (0 +2 \pi n, \pi + 2 \pi n)   $ with $n \in \mathbb N$

- $g(x) = \sin x$ is defined when $x \in (- \infty, \infty)$, therefore $g(\log x)$ is defined when $\log x \in (- \infty, \infty)$

It follows $D_{g \circ f}=(- \infty, \infty)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second you are wrong, I think. $D_{gof}=(0,+\infty)$.

$D_{gof}=\{x|x\in D_f,f(x)\in D_g\}$.

By the way, in the first should be $n\in\mathbb Z$.